# DB Scheme Design for Skygear

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, database-schema, skygear

Should I use relational database schema (3NF) for designing the data storage for Skygear?

For example, I have to usergroup which contains user, should it be Case A or B below?

A.

- User{userId}
- Group{groupId, groupName}
- Grouping(userId, groupId, role}

B.

- Group{userId, groupId, groupName, role}

I think I should be having the following result eventually when passing to the app.

```html
{
   "groupName":"Group A",
   "groupId":"G123",
   "administrator":[
      {
         "userId":"U123"
      },
      {
         "userId":"U456"
      }
   ],
   "creator":{
      "userId":"U123"
   },
   "member":[

   ]
}
```

Comment: Design B is not in 3NF; the same group name is needlessly repeated for every different combination its user id & group id it appears with. An application queries for whatever it wants in terms of the base tables. Relational DBMSs are meant for that. Why do you think that it matters that some query doesn't look the same as some table in the best database design?

Answer (score 1):

3NF is good for data integrity. Everyone love data integrity, but it may not always the first priority when you design an application.

In the case you provided, I will probably opt for A. B requires update of all `Group` if `groupName` is changed.

Beside considering how the data pass to app, try to consider how to update and create too?

---

When to break 3NF in skygear?

*No of user in group.*

In 3NF, you will probably use aggregate func. Skygear does not provide it yet, common way it to add an `user_count` column to `group` record. And update the number when an user is added/removed.

Answer (score 0):

3NF should be used.

Although skygear does not support table joining. It have a Record Relations Data Type for using a foreign key. (although one level only)

https://docs.skygear.io/guides/cloud-db/data-types/android/